# Simple Implementation of Callable with Thread Executor and notify

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to implement a thread pool with some tasks in it that will be done in separate thread(s). Problems are 2: i need a return value and the return value must be used as soon as it is ready. 
For now my code is returning value and working. Problem is i cant check for status of the threads in the main thread because its blocking it that way. I need some callback i dont know how to implement. Some help for a simple example? Ive searched quite a lot and i cannot find something that fits my needs.
This is my `Callable`:

```
public class MyAsyncCallable<V> implements Callable<V> {

    CallbackInterface ci;

    public MyAsyncCallable(CallbackInterface ci) {
        this.ci = ci;
    }

    public V call() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Call of MyCallable invoked");
        System.out.println("Result = " + this.ci.doSomething(10, 20));
        return (V) "Good job";
    }
}

public interface CallbackInterface {
    public int doSomething(int a, int b);
}
```

and main:

```
MyAsyncCallable<String> mac = new MyAsyncCallable<String>((a, b) -> a + b);
ex.submit(mac);
```

How do i get the result without blocking the main thread asking for it?

Comment: What's the point in making it generic if you're going to return a `String`?

Comment: `ex.submit` returns a `Future<String>`. You can get the result from that.

Comment: I know what it does. Problem is i have to `.get()` and if the task is not ready i will get null. Also i cant loop `get()` untill i get a result because it blocks the thread i am calling it in....

Comment: This is why "How do i get the result without blocking the main thread asking for it?"

Comment: Then... pass the future to the thread where you do want to block until it's ready. Some thread has got to wait for it if you want some thread to wait for it. Or just do other stuff in the main thread for long enough that you know evaluation of the future will have completed.

Comment: You can always use [`Future.isDone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) to check if the future is done. Or [`get` with a timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). There are 5 methods in `Future`, and it's pretty obvious which ones don't apply.

Comment: i need to change a view when the result is ready without having to ask for the result myself and pass with the eventQueue back to the main thread when done. Not find a way to ask for it till its done...

Comment: Also if i loop `while(!isDone)` or something similar, i am blocking it again until its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing your application with swing, can't you use inkvokeLater to update your gui at te end of your worker thread?

```
public V call() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Call of MyCallable invoked");
    System.out.println("Result = " + this.ci.doSomething(10, 20));
    //...
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          updateView();
        }
    });
    //...
    return (V) "Good job";
}
```